# docker interpretes entrypoint path as relative?

Tags: windows, docker

Currently debugging a vscode devcontainer, quite odd:

```sh
$ docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR -it --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-282c0b4a9ac1294bc597aabf74e28acf
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

has anyone seen that before? (`/bin/sh` is a real file:

```sh
$ docker run -a STDOUT -a STDERR -it --entrypoint sh vsc-282c0b4a9ac1294bc597aabf74e28acf
# ls /bin/sh
/bin/sh
```

I am very confused...

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @dzh I can not remember - probably worked around it